# como saber si el campo en un select esta vacio y guardarlo en una variable

Tags: mysql

He intentado de mil formas hacer lo siguiente:
quiero validar si el parametro recibido en una funcion mysql es null. Lo he hecho con campo!=null, campo is not null, campo is null, if exists y niguna me funciona. Solo tengo una sucursal en la tabla que e es '001'  pero cuando le mando otra diferente por ejemplo '002' me devuelve que también existe !!!  lo cual no es correcto porque '002 no existe'
El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
 BEGIN
 DECLARE suc varchar(3);

  IF EXISTS(SELECT Sucursal from consecutivo where Sucursal=sucursal) THEN

   set suc='yes';

  ELSE

  set suc='no';

   end IF;


   RETURN suc;

    END
```

Comment: Acabo de descubrir algo interesante si pongo el valor directo si mefuncion perfecto , osea asi: 

set result=(SELECT Sucursal from consecutivo WHERE Sucursal='001' limit 0,1); pero si le paso el parametro no funciona :set result=(SELECT Sucursal from consecutivo WHERE Sucursal=sucursal limit 0,1);

Answer (score 0):

Intentaría con esto:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewProc (IN sucursal VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

    SET suc = (SELECT c.Sucursal from consecutivo c where c.Sucursal= sucursal);
    IF suc IS NULL 
    THEN 
        SELECT 'yes';
    ELSE
        SELECT 'no';
    END IF

END
```

Podrías hacer algo similar para una función.